# Retornar divisível por número em um array

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso percorrer um array em JavaScript onde devo buscar dentre os números do *array* o primeiro numero divisível pelo numero que o usuário irá informar e que esse seja diferente de zero. Tentei criar um código, porém ele não está considerando um valor inteiro na divisão.

```
function busca(array, numero)
{
  
  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(array[i] % numero && -! 0)
    
    return array[i]
}

console.log(busca([0, 7, 4, 15, 18, 3, -1, 323, -5], 2))
```

No caso ao passar o **numero 2** deveria retornar o **numero 4** do array, porém ele esta **retornando o 7**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um erro de sintaxe na comparação, aquilo não faz o menor sentido, tem coisas jogadas de qualquer jeito. Novamente, sem mexer na forma que está fazendo por ser um exercício básico e mantendo a melhor performance:

```js
function busca(array, numero) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] % numero == 0 && array[i] != 0) return array[i];
}

console.log(busca([0, 7, 4, 15, 18, 3, -1, 323, -5], 2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FirstMultiple.js).

E ainda tem um vício de não colocar `;` no fim das linhas, só porque pode não quer dizer que está certo, para economizar uma digitação mínima um dia fará algo que não funciona e perderá horas tentando descobrir o porquê, não faça isso.

Comment: muito obrigado mais uma vez, vou ficar mais atento com relação ao uso do ;

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar aqui só uma opção mais simples:

```
function busca(array, numero) {
  if (numero === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return array.find(val => val > 0 && val % numero === 0);
}

console.log(busca([0, 7, 4, 15, 18, 3, -1, 323, -5], 2));
```

```js
function busca(array, numero) {
  if (numero === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return array.find(val => val > 0 && val % numero === 0);
}

console.log(busca([0, 7, 4, 15, 18, 3, -1, 323, -5], 2));
```

Comment: editei sua resposta para executar o código. Se não gostou, sem problemas, pode retirar.

Answer (score 2):

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(array, num) {
  
  for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
    
    if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
    
      return array[i];
    
    }
  
  }
  
  return console.log("Nenhum número válido encontrado!");
  
}

buscarDivisivelPor([1, 3, 3 ,5, 5 ], 2);

buscarDivisivelPor([1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 ], 2);
```