# Javascript: Problemas ao executar uma função. Como melhorar o código feito?

Tags: javascript, array, funções, if, for

Olá, estou fazendo um curso introdutório de JavaScript e, embora eu consiga imprimir o resultado desejado pelo exercício, a plataforma não reconhece meu código. Gostaria que me ajudassem a melhorar o código ou me oferecessem alternativas em que eu pudesse continuar usando conceitos introdutórios sobre JavaScript.

***A questão é:*** "Programe uma função buscarDivisivelPor que recebe dois parâmetros, um array de números e um número de teste, retornando como resposta o primeiro número do array que seja divisível pelo número dado e diferente de zero. Caso nenhum número do array passe no teste, retorne o texto "Nenhum número válido encontrado!"".

***Os erros apontados pela plataforma são:***

Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 2 a reposta deve ser 4

Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 7 a reposta deve ser 7

Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 8 a reposta deve ser 128

***Meu código***:

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(array, num)
{
  // Escreva abaixo o seu código:

  var invalido =[];

  for(var i=0; i<=array.length;i++){

     if (array[i] % num == 0 && array[i] != 0) {

        var valor = 0;
        valor = console.log(array[i]);

         break; 

         return valor;

      } else {

         invalido.push(array[i]);
      } 

      if (array.length == invalido.length){

         return "Nenhum número válido encontrado!";
      } 
   }
} 
console.log(buscarPorDivisivel([0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5],2));
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Retornar divisível por número em um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461011/retornar-divis%c3%advel-por-n%c3%bamero-em-um-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma possível solução para o seu problema.

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(a, b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if (a[i] !== 0 && a[i] % b === 0) {
            return a[i]
        }
    }
    return "Nenhum número válido encontrado!"
}
```

Poderiamos implementar uma versão utilizando o método filter do tipo array, da seguinte maneira, a função `find` vai retonar o primeiro elemento que a cumpra a condição passada pela função auxiliar:

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(a,b){
    c = a.find(x => x !== 0 && x % b === 0)
    return c || "Nenhum número válido encontrado!"
}
```